# regex_match failure in C++11 using VS12

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I need a function that returns true if a string is a partial comment in C++(lets say it just start with /* as a condition) and i thought that a simple regex should solve my solution fast. Wrote it from scrath, tested it online at http://regex101.com/ and it worked like a charm. But in C++, using the c++11 regex_match, it fails displaying me anything. I'll place the regex in code:

```
regex partialCommReg("(^[\/][\*][\S\s]*$)");
if (regex_match ("/* ", partialCommReg) )
  cout<<"ok";
```

edit: I'm using VS12 as my compiler.

Comment: Tell us what compiler you're using, too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the backslashes within the string literal. A better solution is to use [raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) to avoid having to escape them.

```
regex partialCommReg(R"((^[\/][\*][\S\s]*$))");
//                   ^ ^                   ^
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d97d53c11c010e7e)

Also, your regex can be made a little simpler, this works too:

```
regex partialCommReg(R"((^/\*[\S\s]*$))");
```

---

There seems to be a bug in the VS regex implementation, I was able to reproduce the behavior you're seeing on VS2013. First off, you do have to escape the backslashes, and if you turn the warning level up high enough VS will warn you about illegal escape sequences in the string literal you've posted.

Assuming that's done, your code still won't find a match, and it looks like the part VS doesn't like is this: `[\\S\\s]*`. If you replace that part with `.*`, the code works. All 3 versions below will print `OK`.

```
regex partialCommReg("(^[\\/][\\*].*$)");
regex partialCommReg("(^/\\*.*$)");      // simplified version of the one above
regex partialCommReg(R"((^/\*.*$))");    // uses raw string literals, VS2013 only
```

Comment: 13 IntelliSense: identifier "R" is undefined Source.cpp 54 22 Project1

Comment: @Radu Hmm, [looks like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) raw string literals were added in VS2013. Sorry, you'll have to escape the backslashes as shown in the other answer, or upgrade VS.

Comment: @Radu Yep, looks like it. Behaves the same on VS2013, see updated answer.

Comment: yes, i thought of it in the start, but it won't recognize if i have a \n after /*

Comment: @Radu This will match a newline - `"(^/\\*[.\\s]*$)"`

Answer (score 1):

```
regex partialCommReg("(^[\\/][\\*][\\S\\s]*$)");
```

Notice the escape sequences.  Additionally, if you are using g++, it (regex) is not supported until 4.9.  Prior to that, it just throws an exception when you attempt to do anything (but it will compile).

Comment: still not working. i'm using visual studio 2012's c++. also, testing on http://regex101.com/, it fails.

Comment: @RaduVlad: You're not taking the C++ string literal layer into account. That has its own escaping, on top of that used in the regex. You can't just extract the C++ string literal character-by-character, paste it into regex101.com and expect it to work.

Comment: @RaduVlad What *exactly* did you change based on the 2 answers here?

Comment: code:
regex partialCommReg("(^[\\/][\\*][\\S\\s]*$)");
if (regex_match ("/* ", partialCommReg) )
  cout<<"ok";

never reaches there.

Comment: @RaduVlad `\*` needs to be `\\*` just like the others.